# Calculate the sum of values in input elements using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, input, sum, getelementbyid

I'm trying to compute the sum of many inputs that are displayed, in order to make an invoice. All products that must be invoiced are recorder in my database, and I wrote this JavaScript function to calculate the total:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getItems()
 {
 var items = new Array();
 var itemCount = document.getElementsByClassName("items");
 var total = 0;
 for(var i = 0; i < itemCount.length; i++)
 {
     total = total +  document.getElementById("p"+(i+1)).value;
 }

 return total;
 document.getElementById('tot').value= total;
 }
 getItems()</script>
```

The problem is that I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null`  on the line  `total = total +  document.getElementById("p"+(i+1)).value;`

I really do not understand why, because all my variables are declared.

Comment: It means `document.getElementById("p"+(i+1))` returns null, no element with id `"p"+(i+1)` was found.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You already got the elements by using `getElementsByClassName`, why you are getting it again by id? You can try following:

```
function getItems()
{
    var items = document.getElementsByClassName("items");
    var itemCount = items.length;
    var total = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < itemCount; i++)
    {
        total = total +  parseInt(items[i].value);
    }
    document.getElementById('tot').value = total;
}
getItems();​
```

Answer (score 2):

One or more of the items with an id for `"p"+(i+1)` apparently does not exist.  You didn't show us your HTML so we can't be more specific than that.

But, since you already have a `nodeList` that is an array-like list of the items from `getElementsByClassName()`, there is no need to get them all over again.  As such, you can much more safely rewrite the code to use that and it should also protect you from trying to reference a non-existent item since `getElementsByClassName()` won't return null items.  There are also a couple other issues:

1. You need to convert the results to numbers before doing the addition so you are adding numbers, not strings:

   total = total +  Number(items[i].value);
2. You also need to put the return AFTER you assign the total or the assignment will not get executed:

   document.getElementById('tot').value = total;
   return total;
3. And, since you don't show us your HTML, we don't know what items actually exist so you can protect your code from items that don't exist by using the actual nodeList that comes back get the `getElementsByClassName()` call rather than retrieving items over again.  All items in the nodeList that comes back from that function will exist:

With these changes and some other cleanup, the whole function would look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getItems() {
    var items = document.getElementsByClassName("items");
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        total += Number(items[i].value);
    }

    document.getElementById('tot').value = total;
    return total;
 }
 getItems();
 </script>
```

Comment: Won't this still throw errors when the id doesn't exist? `Number(null.value);` is still incorrect

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem - Since they didn't show their HTML, it's always hard to know exactly what assumptions can be made about their HTML.  In anycase, I change the code to just iterate the itemCount nodeList which will all exist.

Answer (score 1):

try this
**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/aK8aL/3/)**

```
<input type='text' id='p1' class='items' value='10' />
<input type='text' id='p2' class='items' value='10' />
<input type='text' id='p3' class='items' value='10' />
<input type='text' id='p4' class='items' value='10' />
<input type='text' id='tot' value='' />​

function getItems()
{
 var items = new Array();
 var itemCount = document.getElementsByClassName("items");
 var total = 0;
 var id= '';
 for(var i = 0; i < itemCount.length; i++)
 {
   id = "p"+(i+1);
   total = total +  parseInt(document.getElementById(id).value);
 }
document.getElementById('tot').value = total;
return total;
}
getItems();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert from strings to numbers when you parse the value of the inputs, and from number to string when you build the `p` ids.

```
total = total + Number(document.getElementById(id).innerHTML);
var id = 'p'+String(i+1);
```

Here's working code, assuming paragraphs instead of input element: http://jsfiddle.net/dandv/HdwZm/1/

Comment: The code might not be semantic, but it is right because he is using the length property in the for loop :D!